# retrieving a Coc account/game

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'mm about to lose an almost max TH8. I installed Clash of Clans on Android phone to see what it was and i liked it.Then i installed it on my pc and up a new game to almost max TH8 now.

When I was trying to save it, it asked me to load that low level one I had on my phone. I never accept that then my PC crashed then add to format and reinstall COC.

Help and support says they cant help me because I was playing through Bluestacks on my PC. I really don't know what to do now. It took me few months to get there just cant imagine I'm gonna lose it.

Comment: The way I see it, there isn't exactly much we can do to help. We have no control over Clash of Clans whatsoever.

Comment: any idea if it is supercell or bluestacks who could help me get it back?Ty for replying Tex.

Comment: I doubt it. Supercell have already said they can't help you, as you've stated, and I think Bluestacks are in the same position as us; they have no control over the game.

Answer (score 1):

Bluestacks is an Android phone emulator, not a actual 'phone'. Therefore, Supercell cannot help retrieve the account.

I don't think that there is a way to recover your game. My advice is to start a new game and **connect it to your Google account** so you can log in on any device. This happened to me before and I lost my Level 27 TH5 account. I started a new game and I'm now Level 91 and TH9.

**To connect your COC account to your Google account, go to Settings > Devices > Google Play Sign-In**